# How to populate a angular select box based on the value of a boolean

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a Job class with a property of "TESPM" and I also have a class of Employees. One of the Employee Properties is, "EmployeeIsPM". Right now I have a Select box returning the EmployeeIsPM values "true" & "False". But I need the select box to show the 'EmployeeFirstName' & EmployeeLastName of the Employees that are set to "true".

I have a plunkr setup to work on. I couldn't get the input field to display the Current TESPM though.
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/57Ci6ubZ7sacK4P4U83y?p=preview)

```
     <span class="input-group-addon">Select New TESPM</span>
         <select class="form-control" ng-options="job.Employees[0].EmployeeIsPM for job in jobArray" ng-model="Employees[0].EmployeeIsPM">
            <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
         </select>
```

When a New Employee is selected I need the First & Last Name to be inserted in a input field.

```
 <span class="input-group-addon">J. TESPM</span>
 <input style="width:150px" ng-model="currentItem.TESPM" class="form-control" type="text">
```

Update Error in Console Log

```
{TypeError: undefined is not a function
at g.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/MyScripts/app.js:215:15)
at e (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:155:305)
at Ia.| (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:143:226)
at u.constant (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:154:182)
at h [as $render] (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:190:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:172:335)
at g.$digest (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:98:177)
at g.$apply (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:101:12)
at http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:415
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:30:328)
{input:  
{Object
{TypeError: undefined is not a function
at g.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/MyScripts/app.js:215:15)
at e (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:155:305)
at Ia.| (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:143:226)
at u.constant (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:154:182)
at Object.h (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:190:25)
at g.$digest (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:98:177)
at g.$apply (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:101:12)
at http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:415
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:30:328)
at Wb.c (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:323)
{input:  
{Object
```

Line 215 in app.js is

```
 // for all TESPM's
    input.forEach(function (tespm) {
```

Comment: where do you select the manager ? I see you are only showing employees of the manager who has TESPM as true

Comment: not quite sure I am following you....  The Job class has the property "TESPM" That input field is populated with the current Job TESPM.  The Employee class has the boolean to specify they are a project manager. So I have the select box bringing all of the employees from the database. When I select the new employee from the option i need that employees first and last name to populate the input TESPM.  sorry if im not explaining it clear enough.

Comment: ok so first part is showing up the employee firstName and last name in drop down correct? then replicate the same in input box

Comment: Yes correct. Only the employees with EmployeeIsPM set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a custom filter to get the desired employees from the jobArray. In your case the desired employees are the employees(FirstName + LastName) that have the EmployeeIsPM property set to true. So you could use the following implementation:

```
testapp.filter('filterEmployees', function() {
  return function (input) {
    console.log('input: ', input);
    var output = [];
    if (!input instanceof Array) {
      console.log('error');
      return output;
    }
    // for all TESPM's
    input.forEach(function (tespm) {
      var employees = tespm.Employees; 
      if (!employees instanceof Array) {
        console.log('error');
        return output;
      }
      // for all employees
      employees.forEach(function (employee) {
        // filter
        if (employee.EmployeeIsPM) {
          output.push(employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('output: ', output);
    return output;
  };
});
```

The above filter takes a jobArray and returns an array with all the employees for all TESPM, that have EmployeeIsPM == true. I could not understand from your description if you want the employees per TESPM, in that case the filter may need modification.

The select element could get it's options by filtering the jobArray like this (I use a ng-model named selectedPM):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="empl for empl in jobArray|filterEmployees" ng-model="selectedPM">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

If You want the input to display the value that is selected from the dropdown, you could use the same ng-model(that you used in the select element) for the input element like this:

```
<div>
    Project Manager: <input ng-model="selectedPM" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I just switched the ng-model from selectedPM to TESPM. did exactly what I needed!

Comment: There are errors in the console. I am going to edit the question so I can add it

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.21" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='controller1'>
  <h3>Select New Project Manager</h3>

  <select class="form-control" ng-options="job.Employees[0].EmployeeFirstName + ' ' +job.Employees[0].EmployeeLastName as (job.Employees[0].EmployeeFirstName + ' ' +job.Employees[0].EmployeeLastName) for job in jobArray" ng-model="selectedEmployee">
    <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
  </select>



  <h3>Project Manager</h3>

  <div>
    Project Manager:
    <input ng-model="selectedEmployee"  type="text" ></input>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```